# Yii2 session expires after user is idle for a fixed seconds despite session timeouts being set to at least 20 minutes

Tags: session, yii2

```
    'user' => [
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'httpOnly' => true],
    ],
    'session' => [

        'timeout'=>24*60*60,
    ],
```

I have already added these codes in my config/main file

Comment: Is this whole configuration for user and session you've got? Have you checked your current PHP settings for sessions? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes) for some tips.

Answer (score 1):

My answer employs the user of Yii2 user authentication module.

According to the [API documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#login()-detail) for the login method for Yii2, the login method sets the identity cookie to be session based, since the default duration is 0.

```
public boolean login ( yii\web\IdentityInterface $identity, $duration = 0 )
```

However, by specifying the duration when calling the login method, the cookie is stored for the duration specified. As long as cookie-based login is enabled, the user's login would refreshed. See example below.

```
if(Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user, 24 * 60 * 60)) {
    // Login Successful, perform appropriate action here
}
```